# Python Keyboard Module, wait for user

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-keyboard

I'm currently building a python code to play Blackjack where I need to be able to call certain functions uppon keypress without necessarily being in the terminal. I found this keyboard module which helped but I came across this issue.

```
def hit_or_stand(deck,hand):
    global playing
    print ("\nWould you like to Hit or Stand? Enter 'h' or 's'")

    if keyboard.is_pressed('h'):
        hit(deck,hand)  

    if keyboard.is_pressed('s'):
        print("Player stands. Dealer is playing.")
        playing = False
```

Let me explain what this function does as I don't want to overload everyone with the entire code. Essentially this function is called in a loop until the player decides to hit s which declares playing as False and therefore stopping the loop. If the player hits h then the hit function is called which draws a card. The player can draw as many cards.

My problem right now is that this code doesn't wait for user keypress. It loops extremely fast repeating it. I only want it to loop after either h or s is pressed.

I tried using `keyboard.wait('h')` on the line above the first if but then this doesn't allow the user to press s and therefore declare playing as False.

What I'm looking for is something along the lines of `keyboard.wait('h'or's')` but I know this does not work.

Thank you for your help. I am using python 3.7.9

EDIT: Keyboard Module I am referring too:
https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `keyboard.read_key()` to wait for any input.

If it's not `h` or `s` ,`read_key` again.

Comment: Thank you so much I've been looking for documentation on this for the last hour and you fixed my issue in minutes!

Comment: `ImportError: You must be root to use this library on linux`

Answer (score 0):

```
import keyboard

def mywait():
    keyboard.read_key()

def my_function():
    print("Hello")

def my_exit():
    quit()

keyboard.add_hotkey("p", my_function)
keyboard.add_hotkey("esc", my_exit)

while True:
    mywait()
```

Comment: `raise ImportError('You must be root to use this library on linux.')
ImportError: You must be root to use this library on linux.`